# Loading is_file not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I am trying to load file by a data array in codeigniter. But the is file not picking it up.

I can not echo my logo to the view page

What is the best way to get it like below so I can get images as an array.

```
public function index() { 

if (is_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/image/data/logo.png')) {

$data['logo'] =  dirname(FCPATH)  . '/image/' . 'data/logo.png';

} else {

$data['logo'] = '';

}

$this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/header', $data);

}
```

Tried all ready

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Header extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {

    //$this->load->library('document');

    if (is_file(FCPATH) . 'image\data\logo.png') {
    $data['logo'] = FCPATH  . 'image\data\logo.png';
    } else {
    $data['logo'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/header', $data);
   }

}
```

View Header File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog/views/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog/views/theme/default/stylesheet/bootstrap.css">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php echo $logo;?>" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the snippet which doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry don't understand your question. On the view file <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" class="img-responsive">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change FCPATH to base_url() in your header controller file... it works!!

```
if (is_file(base_url()) . 'image/data/logo.png') {
$data['logo'] = base_url()  . 'image/data/logo.png';
} else {
$data['logo'] = '';
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `if (is_file(base_url('image/data/logo.png')))` is what you want. I don't know why my edit was rejected.

Comment: just remove is_file() just put base_url.'/image/data/logo.png'

Comment: Again, it should be `if (is_file(base_url('image/data/logo.png')))`, please refer to the [URL Helper docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: is_file() is use if you are not sure that that is not a file but in your code logo.png is a file you have to use is_file() if you have more conditions not a simple link only that you know that is a file. do you have any condition let say you found the one you type is a directory the return of is_file() is false.......what happen next to your link? nothing right?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index() 
{ 
    if (is_file(FCPATH) . 'image\data\logo.png') 
    {
        $data['logo'] = FCPATH  . 'image\data\logo.png';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $data['logo'] = '';
    }
    $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/header', $data);
}
```

put this.. in your header file put this `"<img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>";`

Comment: try this...http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/71626/#353624

and this http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/73281/#363323

Comment: try this........change your FCPATH......BY base_url()...in your header controller. 
    if (is_file(base_url()) . 'image/data/logo.png') {
    $data['logo'] = base_url()  . 'image/data/logo.png';
    } else {
    $data['logo'] = '';
    }